# Loop through php $_POST, send email with values

Tags: php, email, post

I'm using:

```
foreach($_POST as $name => $value){ 
    $items = $name.': '.$value.' '; 
}

$message = 'FROM: '.$name." \nEmail: ".$email."\nItems: \n".$items;
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

When I send the email it only sends the last $name/value field. I need all name/value pairs from the $_POST array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$items = '';

foreach($_POST as $name => $value){ 
    $items .= $name.': '.$value.' '; 
}

$message = 'FROM: '.$name." \nEmail: ".$email."\nItems: \n".$items;
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: Great that worked. Thanks for the help! Now I am trying to format the $items output into either an html table or neat plain text rows. Can anyone help me with that? Can I wrap $name and $value with <td> tags?

Comment: `$items .= "$name: $value\n";` for text rows

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$items = '';

foreach($_POST as $name => $value){ 
    $items .= $name.': '.$value.' '; 
}

$message = 'FROM: '.$name." \nEmail: ".$email."\nItems: \n".$items;
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked. Now if I can only get the results to display neatly in a table. haha.